# glMultiDrawElements

Tags: opengl

I read the red book (7th edition) and while testing glMultiDrawElements I got nothing on my screen, and "Access violation" error in debug console. I use MVS2010, and here are main code parts I compile:

```
// C4UB_V2F interwined format, vertex are CCW ordered
static const GLfloat vertex[] = {

    // First triangle
    0xff0000ff, 0.25f, 1.0f, // nevermind on that incorrect integer colors
    0x00ff00ff, 0.0f,  0.0f,
    0x0000ffff, 0.5f,  0.0f,

    // Second one
    0xff0000ff, 0.75f, 0.0f,
    0x00ff00ff, 0.5f,  1.0f,
    0x0000ffff, 1.0f,  1.0f

};


void init() {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glInterleavedArrays(GL_C4UB_V2F, 0, vertex);

}


static const GLubyte order[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

static GLubyte oneIndices[] = {0, 1, 2};
static GLubyte twoIndices[] = {3, 4, 5};
static GLsizei count[] = {3, 3};
static GLvoid * indices[2] = {oneIndices, twoIndices};

void render() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // This one works perfectly:
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, order); 

    // And this one generates access violation error
    // in the book there's no indices casting, but MVS2010 is too lazy to cast it itself
    glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (const GLvoid **)indices, 2);


    // This command never executes 'cause of acces violation error occuring 
    glFlush();

}
```

Seems to me I've missed something while casting *indices*, but I can't get what exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks reasonable, although your colors are converted to floats and the float bytes taken as color (use a struct instead), but this shouldn't produce an error.

Comment: As you're new here, make sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: According to unofficial information I see frequently enough, this procedure is just broken. The simple _for_ loop is using instead. I'm not sure it's hardware problems, because both my videocards (Radeon and one built in intel i3 processor) can't execute this.

Comment: The same error occures to glDrawRangeElements (ignoring the fact that glGetIntegerv with IDs GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES and GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES gives pretty big constant values, without any error generating).

Comment: This makes me sad. In addition to `glMultiDrawElements` and `glDrawRangeElements` I've mentioned above, this problems also relative to `glMultiDrawArrays`, `glPrimitiveRestartIndex`, `glDrawArraysInstanced` and `glDrawElementsInstance`. Are they all really broken? I use latest glew and freeglut, if it's important.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the access violation was on a NULL pointer?

Comment: I'm not sure how correctly I got your question, but I just checked - `printf("%i", glDrawElementsInstanced);` is printing zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just checked - printf("%i", glDrawElementsInstanced); is printing zero.

There are two possibilities for that.

1. Your OpenGL implementation doesn't support them. This would mean that you have ancient drivers, or you aren't creating a context properly. Since you're using FreeGLUT, a context creation problem is unlikely. If your hardware was made in the last 7 years, you should be able to get them.
2. You did not *initialize* GLEW. You must call `glewInit` after creating the OpenGL window with FreeGLUT. Otherwise, you will not have properly initialized GLEW, and your function pointers will be NULL.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to initialize glew. *facepalm* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Due to your comments it seems these functions are not supported by your hardware and/or driver. `glMultiDrawElements` is supported from 1.4 on and `glDrawRangeElements` is supported from 1.2 on. Make sure your hardware supports these versions and you got the latest drivers.

And of course you first have to retrieve the corresponding function pointers before you can use them. This can be done manually by means of `wglGetProcAddress` (assuming Windows due to your mentioning of VS) or by an extension loading library, like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, I included GLEW but forgot to initialize it. Thanks!